# Method not Returning Correct Total

Tags: java, methods

I've written a method which returns the maximum occupancy of a hotel, based on whether the beds in each room are single or double.

```
public int calcOccupancy() {
    int total = 0;
    Room roomref;
    Bed bedref;

    for (int x = 0; x < room.size(); x++){
        roomref = room.get(x);

          for (int y = 0; y < roomref.numBeds(); y++){
              bedref = roomref.getBed(y);

              switch(bedref.bedNum()){
              case 1: total = total + 2;
              case 2: total = total + 1;
              default:break;
              }


          }
    }
    return total;
}
```

When I call the method, I seem to be getting pretty random values, although they are never too far off what they should be.

Can anyone figure out what I've done wrong. If needed, I can supply more code from the project.

Comment: You need break statements in your switch. See the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `break`s after the end of your statements:

```
case 1: 
    total = total + 2;
    break;
case 2: 
    total = total + 1;
    break;
```

Otherwise the `total` will be assigned & reassigned over & over.

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly. Out of curiosity, do you have any idea what the code was doing beforehand?

Comment: Seems like it was assigning & reassigning values to the `total` variable. But a `total` of what ? No idea, seems to be something wrong with the method's logic..

Answer (score 2):

Add missing `break;` statements into your switch - otherwise you end up with `total += 3` for case 1.

```
     switch(bedref.bedNum()) {
          case 1: 
             total = total + 2;
             break; //OR OTHERWISE IT WOULD FALL THROUGH
          case 2: 
             total = total + 1;
             break;
          default:
             break;
     }
```

If `bedNum()` refers to "What kind of bed is in that room", you might want to think about an *enum* to keep the possibilies. Much easier to read in the end:

```
 public enum Beds {
    DOUBLE,
    SINGLE; 
 }
```

With the switch

```
 switch(bedref.bedNum()) {
          case SINGLE: 
            total += 1;
            break;
          case DOUBLE:
            total += 2;
            break;
          default:
            break;
 }
```

Or you could even let the enum know about the number of beds:

```
 public enum Beds {
    TWO_SINGLE(2),
    DOUBLE(2),
    SINGLE(1);
    int beds;
    private Beds(int i) {
      beds = i;
    }
    public int getNumberOfBeds() {
      return beds;
    }
 }
```

Reducing your count of total to

```
 total += bedref.bedNum().getNumberOfBeds();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put break statements for each `case`, you will fall through next cases and their code will be executed :

If `case` 1 is matched, code for case 1 **AND** for case 2 will be executed, and you will get `total + 3` as a result.

Correct it like this :

```
switch(bedref.bedNum()){
              case 1: total = total + 2;break;
              case 2: total = total + 1;break;
              default:break;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a break after case 1 as well. Rest all seems fine.

What happens with your code is that after execution goes to "case 1", it does not comes out from the switch block and executes "case 2".